# How to add products to Odoo shopping cart from external site

Tags: odoo, session-cookies, csrf, xml-rpc, odoo-10

I want to connect a external website with the Odoo shopping cart. The site is done using [Odoo web service API](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html), now I want to connect it to Odoo eCommerce.

Watching the traffic when a product is added I see a HTTP POST to */shop/cart/update* with data like:

```
csrf_token=XXX&product_id=99&add_qty=1
```

I also see a cookie with a session_id.

So my question is how to make this cookie and the csrf_token to permit adding products from outside the shopping cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo Support answered that due of security reasons it is impossible to add products from external sites.

Comment: Is this still true as Odoo is now at version 14.0?

Comment: If you have a Java solution to this cart issue I am ready to pay your consulting on that matter.